# SQL query, sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sorting

I have a table with columns transaction_ID, status and modified_date.
Transaction status may have duplicate values but modified_date will be different.
I want to print the latest status of transaction with its ID like a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select * from
(select *, row_number() over(partition by transactionid order by modified_date desc) rn from table) t
whete rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Giorgi Nakeuri But can you tell me what does rn does?

Comment: Rownumber will return you numbers starting from 1 with max date within transaction and will continue 2, 3,4... as date decreases

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, there are several ways to do this - here's one option with `row_number()`:

```
select transaction_id, status, modified_date
from (
    select transaction_id, status, modified_date, 
           row_number() over (partition by transaction_id 
                              order by modified_date desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```